# is this proof complete?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am learning to write proofs in set theory but I am not sure if what I am doing is right...do you think I am on the right track? This is what I am trying to prove

Let $f$ be a function $f:A \to B$. Let $A_n$ be a sequence of subsets of $A$, and let $B_n$ be a sequence of subsets of $B$. Show that
$$f^{-1}(\bigcup_n B_n) = \bigcup_n f^{-1}(B_n).$$

This is what I have so far:

[Proof first attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8soS0.jpg)

Comment: Your question will be more well recieved, and more likely to recieve feedback if you format the work you've done with mathjax syntax (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but no. The first error is in your first line: "We know that every subset of uncountable set is countable." This is not true; consider the uncountable set $\mathbb{R}$ with its uncountable subset, the irrational numbers.

The statement (4) is technically correct but it demonstrates a misunderstanding of what the question is asking. You write, "a function is invertible only if the function is bijective." However, when we write $f^{-1}(X)$, where $X$ is some set, we generally aren't referring to an explicit function $f^{-1}$. Instead, this is shorthand for the preimage or [inverse image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image) of that set. In other words, $f^{-1}(B_n)=\{a\in A\,|\,f(a)\in B_n\}$.

Most of the rest of the statements don't make sense to me as written; for example, (7) says that "$x \in$ union of functions," but you can't take a union of functions. (EDIT: In the comments, Brian M. Scott points out that you can take a union of functions in some circumstances. Still, the way the concept is applied in (7) doesn't make sense.)

I think that you're overcomplicating things. Go back to basics. Let $x \in f^{-1}(\bigcup\limits_n B_n)$. Then, that means that there exists some $b\in\bigcup\limits_n B_n$ such that $f(x)=b$. But $b\in\bigcup\limits_n B_n$ means that there exists some integer $k$ (I assume integers, but the problem should really specify) such that $b\in B_k$. But remember that $f(x)=b$, so $x\in f^{-1}(B_k)$ by definition. After a few more steps, you should be able to conclude that $f^{-1}(\bigcup\limits_n B_n)\subseteq \bigcup\limits_n f^{-1}(B_n)$.

Then, you have to go in reverse and prove that $\bigcup\limits_n f^{-1}(B_n)\subseteq  f^{-1}(\bigcup\limits_n B_n)$. Hopefully, you should be able to do this part yourself, and then your proof will be over.

Welcome to Math StackExchange.

Comment: Since a function is simply a set of ordered pairs, one can indeed take a union of functions; in some set-theoretic arguments one does exactly that. (But (7) is still incoherent.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I hadn't thought about that before, but of course you're right. Given the one-to-oneness of functions, the domains of each individual function would probably need to be disjoint, no? I suppose that taking unions of relations that all act on the same underlying set would probably be pretty interesting as well. I'll make an edit.

Comment: The domains don’t have to be disjoint, though that makes things easier: the functions just have to agree wherever their domains overlap.